# When to refresh an instance using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why do we have to refresh an instance after adding new relations?

Example, theres a pivot table 'favourites' which stores all the favourite relation N:N between items and users:

```
$item = factory(App\Item::class)->create();
$user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
$user->setFavourite($item->id);
dd($user->favourites);//is Empty!!
//whereas refreshing the instance...
$user = $user->fresh();
dd($user->favourites);//is the corresponding collection within the item
```

The setFavourite method is simply an attach/detach of the relationship:

```
public function setFavorito($id)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if($user->esAnuncioFavorito($id)) {
            $user->favoritos()->detach($id);
        }else{
            $user->favoritos()->attach($id);
        }
    }

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

I though that when eloquent calls for the related instances of an instance it was done at the moment, therefore a call to the DB shall be done and would end retrieving an updated collection including the added one.

Could someone explain it to me? When should I use the fresh() method?

Comment: What does your setFavourite() method do?

Comment: adds the item to the user_favourites N:N relationship (updated with the code)